# VBA How to round-off Time to 5 mins from decimal to decimal

Tags: vba, datetime, time, rounding

Could you please help me with the code in VBA to round-off the time to 5 minutes. I have used some of  these functions without success.

```
        varSheetTimeCard.Cells(iRow, 3) = WorksheetFunction.MRound(varSheetTimeDoctorReport.Cells(iRow, 7), "0:05")
    varSheetTimeCard.Cells(iRow, 3) = Math.Round(varSheetTimeDoctorReport.Cells(iRow, 8) * 288, 0) / 288
    varSheetTimeCard.Cells(iRow, 3) = dhRoundTime(varSheetTimeDoctorReport.Cells(iRow, 7), 5)
    varSheetTimeCard.Cells(iRow, 3) = WorksheetFunction.MRound(varSheetTimeDoctorReport.Cells(iRow, 7), "0:05")
    varSheetTimeCard.Cells(iRow, 3) = WorksheetFunction.MRound(varSheetTimeDoctorReport.Cells(iRow, 7), 1 / 288)
```

[image: The figure below shows three columns, First column is the input and 3rd column is the desired output]

Comment: `Round(timeValue * 288, 0) / 288`

Comment: Have you tried `mod`?

Comment: Please explain what "without success" means, especially in regards to `varSheetTimeCard.Cells(iRow, 3) = Math.Round(varSheetTimeDoctorReport.Cells(iRow, 8) * 288, 0) / 288` (i.e did it fail simply because it is using column H instead of column G, or did it do something else wrong?)

Comment: Also, how are the "Total Time (Decimal)" values derived - I can see that they aren't the "Total Time" values expressed as a decimal, but I can't work out what they actually are.

Comment: @TimWilliams - yes, I was surprised to see it in the question as being unsuccessful, because your suggestion is exactly what I would have done.

Comment: @TimWilliams. Great thanks for your suggestions. I will try that option again.

Comment: Finally i have found the reason for this. While the second line of my code was working fine there was another piece of code that was overwriting the output of this line. Solved, Thanks everyone for your support and guidance